# What are the best technique for having a real-time notifications, messages or other stuffs that requires an async request on django?

Tags: python, django

I just want to know if there is a best technique for achieving a async tasks like real-time notifications, messages etc. in django? 
Are django-channels + redis server is ok?
Django celery?

Answer (score 0):

django-channels is ok
but celery usually using for background tasks not for real time